# Displaying an Ico File in a Silverlight 3 Application

Tags: silverlight, image, icons

I need to display favicon.ico files fetched from arbitrary Web Sites as a BitmapImage in a Silverlight 3 application but Silverlight 3's BitmapImage only supports PNG and JPG. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this feature is not built into Silverlight, you'll need to do the decoding yourself.

Consider using the icon decoder implementation from Joe Stegman's blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/jstegman/archive/2009/09/13/silverlight-ico-icon-decoder-parser.aspx